# ASP.Net Core, Angular2 and token based authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, jwt, single-page-application

I'm writing a web application using ASP.NET core for the backend / Service and Angular2 as frontend and have Troubles with authentication / authorization.

In ASP.NET core I got just one html page&controller, HomeController with Index which allows anonymous Access ([AllowAnonymous]). This single page delivers the angular2-app to the Client.

All other communication is using ApiControllers (which in ASP.NET core are just normal Controllers, but the Actions on these Controllers expect and send JSON data. For authentication/authorization I want to use jwt tokens. Users, Roles, Claims etc. are stored in an IdentityDbContext using EF core.

Most tutorials I found are outdated, incomplete or refer to 3rd Party OAuth-solutions. I'm not looking for OAuth, I just want a page with username/Passwort and use Tokens to stay logged in since I'm using all API's to get data to and fro the backend.
I read lots of tutorials, tried a few helpful libs, but still am confused about how to set up the Middleware chain for token-based security. As far as I understand I Need to add the Services for identity since I want to use IdentityDbContext:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  [...]
  services.AddIdentity<IdentityUserEntity, IdentityRoleEntity>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, long>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
  [...]
}
```

But what Middleware do I Need to set up in Configure? Do I Need app.UseIdentity() or would app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(o) enough? Wouldn't UseIdentity shortcut the authentication before the JwtBearer gets a shot at checking for Tokens??

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
  [...]
  app.UseIdentity();
  [...]
  app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(jwtOptions);
  [...]
}
```

I ask because the Client automagically was authenticated after in my TokenController I performed a call to _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(...), even though my client did never receive the jwt. So somehow ASP.NET identity Management found some other way to identify my user after signing in, which of course should not happen.

```
// simplified controller
public class TokenController : Controller
{
  [HttpPost("[action]")]
  [AllowAnonymous]
  public async Task<JsonResult> Login([FromBody]LoginViewModel loginRequest)
  {
    var signin = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loginRequest.Username, loginRequest.Passwort, true, true);
  }

  // this will work even though I don't handle any Tokens in the Client yet, so some other authentication mechanism is at work:
  [HttpGet("test")]
  [Authorize]
  public IActionResult Get()
  {
    return new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value });
  }

}
```

So how do I implement token based authentication *and nothing else*?

[UPDATE]

I'd guess I Need to intercept the Cookie authentication event and reject the principal to disable Cookie auth (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38893778/7021):
But for some reason my event handler never gets called.

```
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
  {
    Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
      OnValidatePrincipal = ValidateAsync
    }
  });

public static async Task ValidateAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
{
  context.RejectPrincipal();
  await context.HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("BsCookie");
}
```

More good reads about auth, Cookies and token:
- http://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-cookieauthenticationmiddleware-in-asp-net-core/
- https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core

Comment: ASP.NET Core doesn't have an OAuth/OpenID server anymore, hence you can't use it to create JWT Token. ASP.NET Core only ships with OAuth authentication providers (for popular services such as google, facebook, microsoft or generic jwt authentication middleware). For creating jwt token you will need a third party library, either identity server 4 or ASOS (AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server)

Comment: I don't need Login via Google/Facebook/..., can't I just sign my own Tokens somehow?

Comment: You missed my question: Authentication works even though I don't handle the token yet

Comment: "_...can't I just sign my own Tokens somehow?_" No you can't, that's what I just said in my comment. There is **no Authentication Server** anymore as part of ASP.NET Core. You need a 3rd party library for that. Only authentication providers are part of ASP.NET Core, **not** the Authentcation server

Comment: Just to be clear: `app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions() { ... } )` call from ASP.NET 4 / MVC 5 is unavailable in ASP.NET Core, which was used in the legacy ASP.NET to create tokens

Comment: Anyway, creating a token is not my question. My question is: why is the api call authenticated after SigningIn even though no token is present??

Comment: Seems you are confusing a few things. Identity (or more specifically the sign in manager) uses cookies for authentication (https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/SignInManager.cs#L195). For `app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication` you need a JWT token and this is not generated by AspNetIdentity. You can't generate it yourself, w/o third party library! That server was removed from ASP.NET Core. You can only use already created JWT Tokens (i.e. when authenticating via facebook then facebook will generate the JWT and you consume it only)

Comment: Your only alternative to using third party library is to create and sign the token yourself, but its not easy to get that right if you are not an security expert (neither I am). That's what OAuth/OpenID server does and even if you say you are not looking for it, its exactly what you are looking for. You need to host your own OAuth/OpenID Server where the user authenticates there and returns the token for the user. It can be in the same application or in a separate one, its up to you. But having it in external is usually better if your Rest API is reasonably big

Comment: Yup, I too thought for UseJwtBearerAuthentication  I'd Need a token - so why in hell is the call to my api authorized even though there is not even a token (yet)??? The call should fail since there is no token, but it does not fail. Instead it is logged in.

Comment: (actually I wanted to use IdentityServer and removed it from my Project for testing purposes, since something was odd - see above, I can call protected APIs even though there is no token)

Comment: `PasswordSignInAsync` creates a cookie which is used for authentication and the cookie is used to authenticate the user with your api. In your case order do not matter (See the link above to the source). `UseIdentity()` only registers the CookieMiddleware (https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/BuilderExtensions.cs#L36-L40). Even if you remove it, you can't login with `PasswordSignInAsync` as it will always create a cookie. If you register `UseIdentity` and `UseJwtAuthentication` they will be call in order. First one to succeed will handle it

Comment: But since you have no token and `PasswordSignInAsync ` creates a cookie, the cookie middleware will always handle it. Basically when you have JWT token you don't need identity in the same server, as everything you need can be provided in JWT (jwt is selfcontained and is identified by validating the signature of the token and its value like expiry date). When you use OAuth server, it may use Identity for handling user, but your API may not need to know about it. OpenIddict is an easy to use ASOS project (ASOS is very lowlevel for creating own OAuth APIs) or IdentServer (never used)

Comment: Ah, ok - so I don't need app.UseIdentity() when I don't plan to use the cookie middleware? Or do I need to disable it somehow in some Options?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132401/discussion-between-tseng-and-sam).

Answer (score 3):

MS has provided basic jwt token based authentication lib, you can see how to use it here:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-achieve-a-bearer-9448db57

In startup.cs, firstly config Jwt Beare

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions()
          {
              TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                IssuerSigningKey = TokenAuthOption.Key,
                ValidAudience = TokenAuthOption.Audience,
                ValidIssuer = TokenAuthOption.Issuer,
                // When receiving a token, check that we've signed it.
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                // When receiving a token, check that it is still valid.
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                // This defines the maximum allowable clock skew - i.e. provides a tolerance on the token expiry time 
                // when validating the lifetime. As we're creating the tokens locally and validating them on the same 
                // machines which should have synchronised time, this can be set to zero. Where external tokens are
                // used, some leeway here could be useful.
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0)
            }
        });
```

Now you can add to services

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
         services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
          {
            auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme‌​)
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
        });
```

Finally, use it in controller, simply add  [Authorize("Bearer")]

```
   [Route("api/[controller]")]
   public class ValuesController : Controller
   {
      [HttpGet("GetStaff")]
      [Authorize("Bearer")]
       public IActionResult GetStaff()
      {
          List<string> model = new List<string>();
          foreach (User user in UserStorage.Users ){
           model.Add(user.Username);
          }
          return Json(model);
      }
    }
```

Check full details here: https://github.com/Longfld/ASPNETcoreAngularJWT