# Setting cookie expiration in Blazor server app using Azure AD for authentication

Tags: .net-core, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

I created a simple .NET 6 Blazor Server app and followed some tutorials to add authenticate through Azure AD. Everything works fine, but when using the application hours later after it sitting idle I was not asked to login again. I noticed that the *.AspNetCore.Cookies* that gets set has Session expiration, so am guessing I'd need to close the browser, but I'd rather have a set expiration time if idle. Is that something that would be setup in Azure AD or in the application code?

My App.razor XML is wrapped with <CascadingAuthenticationState>. My appsettings.json has the AzureAd config. Here's the code being used in my Program.cs (mostly just defaults from creating new project and added auth code from tutorials):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: [What is the correct way to set a cookie expiration when using Azure AD to login users to an ASP.NET Core 5 Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70981046/what-is-the-correct-way-to-set-a-cookie-expiration-when-using-azure-ad-to-login)

I only needed to make a minor modification, instead of *this.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAD").Bind(options)*, I used *builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAD").Bind(options)*.

It's also worth mentioning that it does NOT change the cookie expiration, it continued to be a session cookie, but I guess somewhere in the application the session does expire and it will go back to Azure AD for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the expiration time of your cookie in your app code by using the CookieAuthenticationOptions class. You can also use the OnValidatePrincipal event to check if the cookie is still valid or not.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .AddCookie(options => {
                    options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30); // set your desired expiration time here
                    options.SlidingExpiration = true; // renew the cookie if it is accessed before expiration
                    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
                    {
                        OnValidatePrincipal = < your custom function here > // validate the cookie identity
                     };
                })
  .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38890172/how-to-handle-cookie-expiration-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: Actually, I would suggest to use [ExpireTimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.expiretimespan?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-authentication-cookies-cookieauthenticationoptions-expiretimespan) instead. The [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.cookie?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-authentication-cookies-cookieauthenticationoptions-cookie) specifies that "Expiration is currently ignored".

Comment: @Nb777 I tried adding the .AddCookie() call as instructed above, but then on app.Run() I get the following error: "Scheme already exists: Cookies"